Hausdorff dimension if Hausdorff measure is infinity
I am reading the article "Cyclic Functions in Lp(R), 1≤p<∞" from Joseph M. Rosenblatt and Karen L. Shuman. In Theorem 5 they calculate the Hausdorff dimension of the set E, which is a perfect set obtained by making dissections as done in the article "On singular monotonic functions whose spectrum has a given Hausdorff dimension" from R. Salem. The theorem and proof are as follows:
Theorem:
There exists a set $F \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\operatorname{dim}_H(F)=\alpha$ and such that $F$ supports a measure $\mu$ with $\hat{\mu} \in L^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}(\mathbb{R})$.
Proof:
Let $E \subset[0,1]$ be a symmetric set of measure zero and let $\theta$ be the standard Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure on $E$. Suppose we have a function concave function $h$ such that the $h$-measure of $E$ is non-zero. Let $\mu=\mathbb{W}(\theta)$. Then $\hat{\mu} \in L^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}(\mathbb{R})$ provided that
$$
h(x)=O\left(x^{\alpha / 2} \log ^{-2 \alpha-1}\left(x^{-1}\right)\right) \text { as } x \rightarrow 0 .
$$
Set
$$
h(x)=x^{\alpha / 2} \log ^{-2 \alpha-1}\left(x^{-1}\right) .
$$
Then $h$ is concave for small enough positive values of $x$. The construction of $E$ is controlled by the ratios of dissection $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots$ where each $\xi_n<1 / 2$. We want to choose $\xi_n$ such that $h\left(\xi_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \xi_n\right)=O\left(2^{-n}\right)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. We look for a formula for $\xi_n$ so that
$$
\left.\left(\xi_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \xi_n\right)^{\alpha / 2} \log ^{-2 \alpha-1}\left(\left(\xi_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \xi_n\right)^{-1}\right)\right)=O\left(2^{-n}\right) \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty .
$$
Since it will be hard to work with $\xi_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \xi_n$ in both factors, we make the estimate $\log \left(\xi_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot \xi_n\right)^{-1}=O(n)$. Equation (3.6) is valid when
$$
\xi_n=2^{-\frac{2}{\alpha}}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{2}{\alpha}(2 \alpha+1)} .
$$
Cyclic Functions
295
With this choice of $\xi_n, \operatorname{dim}_H(E)=\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $h$ and $g$ are of the same order. Let $F$ be the image of $E$ under the Wiener process $\mathbb{W}$ and let $\mu=\mathbb{W}(\theta)$. Then $\operatorname{dim}_H F=\alpha$ and $\hat{\mu} \in L^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}$.
$\square$
My question is how they see that $\dim_H(E)=\frac{\alpha}{2}$.
My attempt:
With this definition of $h$ it is easy to show that the absolute value of the $h$-measure $|\mathcal{H}^h(E)|$ of $E$ is positive and finite. Furthermore, I found on the internet that if $\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$ if $x\to0$, we have $\mathcal{H}^h(E)=0$ if $\mathcal{H}^g(E)=\infty$. Letting $g(t)=t^\frac{\alpha}{2}$ and $h$ as before, we have $\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}\to 0$ if $t\to 0$, so that $\mathcal{H}^\frac{\alpha}{2}(E)=\infty$. But if the Hausdorff measure of $E$ with respect to $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ is $\infty$, how can we show that the Hausdorff dimension of $E$ is $\frac{\alpha}{2}$?
Thanks in advance!

I haven't tried to understand/follow what you want to do, but regarding sets with Hausdorff dimension $\alpha$ that have infinite Hausdorff $\alpha$-measure (and more generally for Hausdorff measure/gauge functions), see Construction of null sets with prescribed Hausdorff dimension and generalizations AND Existence of dimension function (i.e., exact gauge function) AND example; $H^t(K)=\infty$, and $H^s(K)=0$ for all $s > t$}.
